# hypercentre of group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a group and $Z^∗(G)$ be it hypercenter. Suppose $z_1,z_2∈Z^∗(G)$ and $x\in G$. Is it true that the group $\langle xz_1,x^iz_2\rangle$, where $gcd(\circ(x),i)=1$, always generate a nilpotent subgroup? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what $\gcd(o(x),i)$ means when $o(x)$ is infinite, and it is not completely clear whether you mean the subgroup for some specific $i$ or where you are including all such $x^iz_2$ among the subgroup generators. But in any case, it looks like a finitely generated subgroup of the hypercentral group $\langle x, Z^*(G) \rangle$, and hypercentral groups are known to be locally nilpotent.

Comment: I'm sorry. Actually the group is a finite group.

Comment: Can you provide me a reference for that. Thank you.

Comment: A reference for what? If the group is finite, then hypercentral is the same as nilpotent.

Comment: The same proof as in http://math.stackexchange.com/a/717857/583 works. Just use the two lemmas to conclude $\langle x, Z^n(G) \rangle$ is nilpotent.

Comment: But $\langle x,Z^n(G) \rangle$ has the rather obvious central series $1 \le Z^1(G) \le Z^2(G) \le \cdots \le Z^n(G) \le \langle x,Z^n(G) \rangle$.  (In fact you can leave out the $Z^n(G)$ if you like).