# Let $G$ be a group and $x \in G$. Is it true that $\langle x, Z^*(G) \rangle$ is always nilpotent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $x \in G$. Is it true that $\langle x, Z^*(G) \rangle$ is always nilpotent? I know that it is locally nilpotent. If it is not, then an example will be grateful. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is $\;Z^*(G)\;$ ?

Comment: The hypercenter of $G$.

Comment: Yes, just follow the ascending hypercentral series of $G$ with $\langle x,Z^*(G) \rangle$, and you get a hypercentral series of $\langle x,Z^*(G) \rangle$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for your help.

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717813/nilpotent-subgroup-and-hypercenter